# How to blacklist a topics to exclude it from consumption from a particular consumer group in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

We have different consumer groups which consumes data from different topics.We have different partitions of the topic.We need to allow some consumer groups to have access to a particular topic so that only those groups can read from the topics.I was trying out Confluent Kafka Access control lists like this:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer    --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --consumer --topic test-topic --consumer-group Group-1
```

However as we understand it the ACLs can block access to Users and host addresses.Could we use ACLs to block consumer groups as well? If not is there any command that'll help me do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ACLs on Consumer Groups isn't at all secure because any consumer can change their own group.id value. ACLs need to work off secure authentication credentials that cannot be spoofed or faked easily like X.509 Digital Certs or SASL/Kerberos credentials

Comment: I agree but can I use ACL to prevent Consumer Groups from reading into topics.I think ACLs can be used to prevent users and host names.I am trying to get a python /node .js code which will allow me to prevent certain consumer group to read from a topic.I am using Confluent.

Comment: No I don't think you can use ACLs that way. At least not without writing custom code.